# Grouping SQL results at 2 sub levels

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using an Access front end screen and SQL queries at the back end. I am trying to get a result set that is grouped at 2 levels: Region & Month and then a relevant count of total clients active in that period, clients with orders and clients without orders all within the period selected by the user.

Below are the 2 tables in use

**Client Table A**

```
    ID   |  Region   |  StartDate  |   Name
     1   |  North    |   1 Jan 16  |   ABC
     2   |  North    |   1 Mar 16  |   DEF
     3   |  East     |   1 Jul 16  |   GHE
     4   |  East     |   1 Aug 16  |   HIJ
     5   |  West     |   1 Feb 16  |   KLM
     6   |  West     |   1 Mar 16  |   NOP
     7   |  South    |   1 Apr 16  |   QUR
     8   |  South    |   1 Jan 16  |   STU
```

**Orders Table B**

```
    OrderID | Client ID   |Order Date
     1      |    1        | 15 Mar 16  
     2      |    3        | 15 Jul 16  
     3      |    5        | 15 Jun 16  
     4      |    8        | 15 Jul 16  
     5      |    6        | 15 Jul 16  
     6      |    4        | 15 Jan 16  
     7      |    2        | 15 Feb 16  
     8      |    1        | 15 Jul 16  
     9      |    3        | 05 Aug 16  
    10      |    3        | 16 Jul 16  
    11      |    2        | 15 May 16  
    12      |    4        | 15 May 16  
    13      |    6        | 15 May 16  
    14      |    7        | 15 Mar 16
```

The User picks a start date and end date for the report for Eg 1 May 2016 to 31 Jul 16
I need a query that will evaluate if  client start date is within reporting period and produce the following out put:

**Result Set**

```
    Region | Month  |Total Clients|Clients with Orders|Clients w/o Orders
    North  |May-2016|   2         |   1               |     1
    North  |Jun-2016|   2         |   0               |     2
    North  |Jul-2016|   2         |   1               |     1
    East   |May-2016|   0         |   0               |     0
    East   |Jun-2016|   0         |   0               |     0
    East   |Jul-2016|   1         |   1               |     0
    West   |May-2016|   2         |   1               |     1
    West   |Jun-2016|   2         |   0               |     2
    West   |Jul-2016|   2         |   1               |     1
    South  |May-2016|   2         |   0               |     2
    South  |Jun-2016|   2         |   0               |     2
    South  |Jul-2016|   2         |   1               |     1
```

Ive been stuck on this for 2 weeks now.. Please Help!!!

if it helps this is how far I have gotten

```
    PARAMETERS startDt DateTime, endDt DateTime, loc Text ( 255 );
    SELECT DISTINCT a.[Region] AS Region, 
    Format(b.[Orderdate],"MMM-YY") AS MonthOrder, 
    (Select Count(CMet.[clientID]) as cnt  from 
    (SELECT distinct b.[orderID], Format(b.[order date],"MMM-YY") 
    as Contact_Month, a.[clientID], a.[Region]
    FROM Client as a 
    INNER JOIN orders AS b ON a.[client ID] = b.[client id]
    WHERE iif(isnull(loc),a.[REgion] like '*',instr (loc,a.[region]))
    and (b.[orderdate] between startDt and endDt)  
    and (a.[Start date] < startDt) 
    GROUP BY a.[Region], Format(b.[order date],"MMM-YY"), 
    a.[clientID], a.[Region]
    HAVING count(a.[clientID]) >=1) as CMet) AS Clients_Met, 
    (select count([client id]) from clients where 
    iif(isnull(loc),[region] like '*',instr (loc,[region])) and 
    client.[Start date] < startDt AS Total_Client, 
    (Total_Client-Clients_Met) AS Not_Met, 
    format(Clients_Met/iif(Total_Client =0,1,Total_Client),'##.##%') AS Met_Percentage
    FROM clients AS a 
    INNER JOIN orders AS b ON a.[client ID]=b.[client id]
    WHERE iif(isnull(loc),a.[region] like '*',instr (loc,a.[region]))
    and (a.[Start date] < startDt 
    GROUP BY a.[region], Format(b.[order date],"MMM-YY")
    HAVING count(a.[client id]) >=1
    ORDER BY a.[region];
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution below.  The idea is to do the grouping in the inner query, then do the summing in the outer one:

```
SELECT Region, Month, Count(ID) AS Clients, Sum(HasOrder) AS ClientsWithOrders, 
    [Clients]-[ClientsWithOrders] AS ClientsWithoutOrders
FROM (SELECT Region, CDate(Month([Order Date]) & "/1/" & Year([Order Date])) AS [Month], 
      ID, Max(IIf([Client ID]=[ID],1,0)) AS HasOrder
      FROM Orders, Client
      WHERE ((([Order Date])>=#5/1/2016# And 
          ([Order Date])<DateAdd("d",1,#7/31/2016#)))
      GROUP BY Region, CDate(Month([Order Date]) & "/1/" & Year([Order Date])), ID) 
         AS RegionMonthClient
GROUP BY Region, Month
```

The difficulty is I'm getting different results from you.  For example, for East clients (3,4) I see one with an order in May (client 4) and one with an order in July (client 3).

Is this approach useful to you in any way?

Comment: Yes, the result set may be incorrect coz i was manually doing it. Let me try this aproach and see if i get the intended result. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: i think i understand your logic and feel like its getting closer to what I need. The challenge now is that my clientID is alpha numeric so Max wont work. how do I ensure it counts the client only once even if there are multiple orders in the same month?

Comment: Aaah i just realised the Max is being used to count the 1.. my bad.. will review again

Comment: Ok. I have tried this in the production database and unfortunately this gives me a result set that runs into millions due to the nature of the join. I tried to play around with diff join types and the result gets skewed. We have about 10k clients with each ordering about 5-6 times a month. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You might try extracting the logic that selects the row headers (Region, Month) into a separate query or table. You could also simplify my example by cross joining between client and month only, and then left joining to orders. If performance is still an issue maybe someone else will have a better suggestion.

Comment: Im now considering using VBA to loop through the result set from SQL. I know this ain't efficient either but its crunch time and thats the best solution I can think of. Thank you for efforts though. Feel a bit more enlightened with awesome people like you.!

Comment: Perhaps this solution might be better suited to a situation with a smaller dataset.  If you found it instructive in any way though I'm glad for it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the join statement and to check the date use the BETWEEN operation. Here is the link for sample [join statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [Between Opration](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).

Comment: Joins is the basic thing. How do I count 3 different parameters while grouping them at 2 levels.

Comment: You want to add three parameters? You can use something like this select q1, sum(q2), sum(q3),sum(q4), sum(q2)+sum(q3)+sum(q4) as q5 from table group by q1

Comment: I have tried the Sum function as well and it gives me the same result set.